# Confusion regarding object destructuring

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, object-destructuring

I've a RTK query which takes email and password as arguments and returns login info from the server.

RTK QUERY code

```
const authService = createApi({
  reducerPath: "auth",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://localhost:8000/auth/" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    authLogin: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ email, password }) => ({
        url: "login",
        method: "POST",
        body: { email, password },
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

Function which invokes `authLogin`(from elsewhere) by passing email and password as required by the query.

```
const [authLogin, response] = useAuthLoginMutation();

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    authLogin({ email, password });
  };
```

I don't understand why despite being destructured as ({email, password}) in `authLogin` query call, the body still takes in email and password with curly braces?
If email and password are already destructured in the query call, shouldn't the code be `body:(email, password)` instead of `body:{email, password}`?

I do realize that I'm missing something very basic(regarding objects and destructuring), perhaps someone could explain where I'm going wrong in simple words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body: { email, password },
```

is just the [shorthand version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) of

```
body: { email: email, password: password },
```

**No destructuring going on at this point**, just a POJO.

---

Using

```
body: (email, password)
```

would also be valid syntax using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), but it would result in `body` being assigned the `string` `password`.

> The comma operator (,) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Also in query:({email, password}), the email and password are destructured right? So if it is, can I also write props( as in query:(props)) and later use it inside body? Like body:({email:props.email, password:props.password}). Are they the same?

Comment: Yes, they are the same in result, just not using destructuring, which allows for far more consise code.